# Fetched data from ajax in component is not rendering in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

Following [this](http://jamesknelson.com/learn-raw-react-no-jsx-flux-es6-webpack/). I have created a component and from that trying to fetch data using ajax request. I have written code for rendering it but it's not working and also no error after page load. I am new to react so not much idea, probably that's why unable to inspect the issue. Any help will be great.

```js
// Js
React.createElement('tbody', {}, UserItem)

// Component
var UserItem = React.createClass({
propTypes: {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  email: React.PropTypes.string,
  dob: React.PropTypes.string,
},

getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    users: []
  }
},

showResults: function(response) {
  this.setState({
    users: response
  })
},

search: function(URL) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: URL,
    success: function(response){
      this.showResults(response);
    }.bind(this)
  });
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  this.search("users/usersData");
},

render: function() {
  return (
    UserItems
  )
},
})

var UserItems = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var resultItems = this.state.users.map(function(result) {
      return React.createElement(ResultItem, {id:result.id, name:result.name});
    });

    return React.createElement('div', {}, resultItems);
  },
})

var ResultItem = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return React.createElement('tr', {}, 
      React.createElement('td', {}, this.props.id),
      React.createElement('td', {}, this.props.name),
      React.createElement('td', {}, this.props.name),
      React.createElement('td', {}, this.props.name)
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: it should not be like `this.showResults()` it should be `var self = this;` and inside the success handler `self.showResults(response)`

Comment: Do I have to define the self variable globally or just for ```showResults()``` and do I have to change it into ```bind``` too?

Comment: nope not needed inside search function

Comment: did it help you

Comment: No It didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `render()` method.

Something similar to this one should work:

```
render: function() {
 return (
  <div>
    {this.state.users.map(function(user){
       return <h2>{user}</h2>
     })}
  </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: I cannot use this code I need to make this into a table and since I am not using jsx that's why also getting errors for angular brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
search: function(URL) {
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: URL,
    success: function(response){
      self.showResults(response);
    }.bind(this)
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to call `onChange`  too

Comment: I am just doing this on page load then why need to call onChange?

Comment: That's the biggest problem, there is no error in console.

Comment: can you pint `console.log(response)` in the `showResults` function before `this.setState()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124279/discussion-between-aavrug-and-aatif-bandey).